# Taxonomy Templates

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I don't quite understand how to link to my taxonomy templates. Do I need to make a page-tempalte and query my terms from there? I'm using the taxonomy hierarchy currently:

**Taxonomy**

```
$labels = array(
        'name'              => __( 'Product Categories' ),
        'singular_name'     => __( 'Product Category' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Product Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Product Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Product Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Product Category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Product Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Product Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Product Category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Product Categories' ),
    ); 
    $args = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_in_nav_menus' =>  false,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'rewrite'           =>  array('slug' => '/products', 'with_front' => false),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'protax', 'product', $args );
```

Then I have a taxonomy template : `taxonomy-protax.php` which I should be able to get to via `www.mywebsite.com/products` but it keeps leading to 404. Taxonomy template always seem to give me the most trouble... How do I view my `taxonomy-protax.php` page?

Comment: _"which I should be able to get to via `www.mywebsite.com/products`"_  No. You should be able to get a **term** archive with `www.mywebsite.com/products/a-term`, WordPress has no **taxonomy archive**, but **term archives**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display):

> taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php - If the taxonomy were sometax, WordPress would look for taxonomy-sometax.php

**What I do** when using custom taxonomy/custom post types is exactly what you mentioned in the second sentence. Make a page template and a page in the back end. Choose the template you built as the template to use when making your page.

[image: Template Selector]

**EDIT**

Just noticed that you're getting a 404. In that case, check your permalink structure as well.

Again, from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#404_Error):

> If your site uses custom permalinks, you will need to flush your permalink structure after making changes to your taxonomies, or else you may see a "Page Not Found" error. Your permalink structure is automatically flushed when you visit Settings > Permalinks in your WordPress dashboard.

Comment: Right, I guess just because I have taxonomy doesn't mean WP will automatically create a url based on it, I would infact have to create a page for it. I guess it's not a huge deal but kind of inconvenient.